# Create RTF file using MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a task to create a rtf file in MFC. i.e. to read the data from xml file and parse the rft content and create the rtf file. I parsed the RTF content and created a file file1.rtf using CFile, but the output file doesnt display the content properly. Is there any other way to create the file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I've found is to use a RichTextBox control (either on a dialog or created dynamically). Use the control's methods to build your content.